# How can i add Audit Actions to Audit table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can i add Audit Actions to Audit table. I have the following table and trigger to track changes. which store but i want to see the specific changes made. forexample; if update field x value from 1 to 5. I want to see that on Audit Entry which tells me field x of this record  is changed from 1 to 5 . currently i get two rows as shown below

```
  <deleted PART_x0020_LOOKUP_x0020_H="1005551 ,Part:  .325 ,  , , ()" STOCK_x0020_NO="1005551" PART_x0020_LOOKUP_x0020_Vold="1005551 ,Part:  , , , ()" PART_x0020_LOOKUP_x0020_Hnew="1005551 ,Part:  .325 " SIZE=".325" Created_x0020_By="IT-1" Updated_x0020_Date="Jun  2 2017 10:08AM" Last_x0020_Updated_x0020_By="IT-1" SALES_x0020_DESCRIPTION=" .325 " PURCHASE_x0020_DESCRIPTION=" .325 " ITEM_x0020_DESCRIPTION=" .325 " PART_x0020_LOOKUP_x0020_V="1005551 ,Part:  , , , ()" Created_x0020_Date="Jun  2 2017 10:07AM" />
```

and

```
<deleted PART_x0020_LOOKUP_x0020_H="1005551 ,Part:  .325 ,  , , ()" STOCK_x0020_NO="1005551" PART_x0020_LOOKUP_x0020_Vold="1005551 ,Part:  , , , ()" PART_x0020_LOOKUP_x0020_Hnew="1005551 ,Part:  .325 " SIZE=".325" Created_x0020_By="IT-1" Updated_x0020_Date="Jun  2 2017 10:08AM" Last_x0020_Updated_x0020_By="IT-1" SALES_x0020_DESCRIPTION=" .325 " PURCHASE_x0020_DESCRIPTION=" .325 " ITEM_x0020_DESCRIPTION=" .325 " PART_x0020_LOOKUP_x0020_V="1005551 ,Part:  , , , ()" Created_x0020_Date="Jun  2 2017 10:07AM" />
```

//Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditAll](
    [AuditId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [TableName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [AuditEntry] [xml] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AuditAll] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AuditId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

and here is the trigger on table

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[AuditSimple] 
 ON  [dbo].[PARTS]
 AFTER  INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
 AS 
 BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) > 0 
begin
    Declare @AuditMessage XML
    --set valut to all xml from deleted table
    set @AuditMessage =  (select * from deleted for xml auto) 

    insert into AuditAll(DateTime,TableName,AuditEntry) 
        values (GetDate(),'Simple',@AuditMessage )
end

END
```

Comment: As a caution, I would keep really close track of how many records/values are being updated, otherwise this table will blow up really huge insanely fast. Make sure you don't have any automatic processes running updating anything in these tables on a regular basis (even timestamps), and be especially careful that you don't have other triggers in turn triggering these triggers.

Comment: @DoctorT Thank you that make sense . What do you recommend me?

Comment: I am not sure how to get the level of data you are requesting from this logging... but it seems to me that manually storing all this data within the database could be very dangerous, even for a relatively small database. I would recommend looking into the database logging tools built into SQL Server and see if something already exists that can do what you need without all of these automatic triggers firing all the time. I am curious to see what the other responses are though, to see if someone more knowledgeable has a specific answer for you.